# Renaming and Dropping Columns using a Key from different Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use lookup a column value using a key to change the name of a column and drop irrelevant columns based on the other key table.

For example, I'm trying to use this table of key values:

| Country | cat_number | category | category_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 1 | cat_1 | income_tax |
| USA | 2 | cat_2 | property_tax |

to rename the columns and drop the irrelevant columns in this data source:

| Country | cat_1_positive | cat_2_positive | cat_3_positive | cat_1_negative | cat_2_negative | cat_3_negative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| USA | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| USA | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

into this as the final data frame in python:

| Country | income_tax_positive | property_tax_positive | income_tax_negative | property_tax_positive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| USA | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| USA | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

In other words, I'm simply trying to map the Cat_1 names to the corresponding long form category_name in the other dataframe, and dropping columns that do not appear in the key table.

For code examples:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {'Country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA'], 'cat_1_positive': [1, 0, 1], 'cat_2_positive': [0, 1, 1], 'cat_3_positive': [0, 0, 0],'cat_1_negative': [1, 1, 1], 'cat_2_negative': [1, 0, 1], 'cat_3_negative': [0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df.head()
```

```
key_dict = {'Country': ['USA', 'USA'], 'cat_number': [1, 2], 'category': ['cat_1', 'cat_2'], 'category_name': ['income_tax', 'property_tax']}
key = pd.DataFrame(key_dict)
key.head()
```

to the hopeful final version:

```
final = {'Country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA'], 'income_tax_positive': [1, 0, 1], 'property_tax_positive': [0, 1, 1] ,'income_tax_negative': [1, 1, 1], 'property_tax_negative': [1, 0, 1]}
final = pd.DataFrame(final)
final.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't think of a better way but this works:

```
def rename_column(col, d):
    for k in d:
        if k in col:
            return col.replace(k, d[k])
    return None

d = dict(zip(key["category"], key["category_name"]))
d["Country"] = "Country"
df = df.rename(columns={col: rename_column(col, d) for col in df.columns})
df = df[[c for c in df.columns if c is not None]]
```

Comment: This looks super close to what I need ^^ But I am getting a "dict is not callable" error message.

Comment: @ZachDorflinger - Please rename your dict to `d`. You are using `dict` which is a keyword in Python.